# Showing edit link beside a comment on a group_message page only when the comment was made by session user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to show edit link for group_message_comment on a group_message page only when it was posted by the session user.

Talking about group_messages, I managed to show edit links only when it is the session user.

```
  <% if @isme %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_message_path(@group_message) %>
  <% end %>
```

On the other hand,
talking about group_messages_comments, I failed to show edit links. I have no idea about this. Could you help me?

☆show.html.erb(group_messages_controller)

```
           <p><b>Post:</b></p>
                <div class="each_message">
                  <%= image_tag @group_message.group.imageurl,:width => '20', :height => '25' %><%= "(" + @group_message.group.name + ")" %>
                    <p>
                      <%= 'Page:' + @group_message.page.to_s + '＆' %><%= 'Line:' + @group_message.line.to_s %>
                      <a href="/members/<%= @group_message.member.id%>"><%= @group_message.member.name %></a>
                     (<%= @group_message.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)
                    </p>
                 <div class="group_message">  
                  <p class="message_content"><%= @group_message.content %></p>
                 </div><!--group_message-->
                 <br/> 
                 <% if @isme %>
                   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_message_path(@group_message) %> 
                 <% end %>
                </div><!--each_message-->  
                 <hr/>

                  <b>Comments:</b>
                     <% if @group_message.group_message_comments.present? %>
                       <% @group_message.group_message_comments.each do |gmsc|%>
                         <div class="group_message_comment">
                         <p><a href="/members/<%= gmsc.member ? gmsc.member.id : "unknown" %>"><%= gmsc.member ? gmsc.member.name : "unknown" %></a>  (<%= gmsc.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)</p>
                         <%= gmsc.content %> 
                         <p>
                            <% if @isme_comment %>
                              <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_message_comment_path(@group_message.group_message_comments) %> 
                            <% end %>
                         </p>
                      </div> <!--group_message_comment-->
                      <br/>
                     <% end %><!-- each do -- >
                  <% else %> 
                      <ul>
                          <li>no comment yet.</li>
                      </ul>
                  <% end %> <!--if -->
```

☆group_messages_controller

```
  def show
    if !checklogin? then return end
      @group_message = GroupMessage.find(params[:id])
      @isme = me? @group_message
      @group_message_comment = GroupMessageComment.new
      @group_message_comment = GroupMessage.find(params[:id]).group_message_comments.build
      @isme_comment = me? @group_message_comment<!#########--maybe this is wrong-->

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @group_message }
    end
  end
```

☆application_controller

```
def me? obj = nil
     id_num = obj !=nil ? obj.member_id : params[:id].to_i
     if session[:user_id] == id_num then
        return true
     else
        return false
     end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added this and made it. Thank you for your attentions.

```
 <% if @gmsc_member_id == gmsc.member.id  %>
                              <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_message_comment_path(gmsc) %> 
                            <% end %>
```